# Rescaling the Uehling potential formula

Tags: quantum-field-theory, potential, units

I found that the Uehling potential equation is written in natural units in many books and research papers. But because I’ve to make some calculations with the Uehling correction, the formula must be written in non-natural scales. The whole Uehling potential I found [here](https://dx.doi.org/10.1140/epjd/e2018-80457-8) ([SciHub](https://sci-hub.se/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjd/e2018-80457-8)) is given as

$$U(x)= \frac{-e^2}{4π ϵ_0 x}(1+\frac{2α}{3π}∫_0^∞(\frac{1}{z^2}+\frac{1}{2z^4})exp⁡(\frac{-2zx}{λ ̅_C})\sqrt{z^2-1}dz)$$

Whereas, $ λ ̅_C$ is the reduced Compton wavelength, and $ α $ is the fine-structure constant.
In the same paper i found, the above formula is rewritten as,

$$U(x)=\frac{-e^2}{4π ϵ_0 x}+δ(x)$$

One of the numerical solutions of $δ(x)$ in the research paper (in paper 2 in the research paper i mentioned [here](https://sci-hub.se/https://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjd/e2018-80457-8) ), and the solution I want rescale is,

$$δ(x)=-\frac{2αe^2}{12π^2ϵ_0 x}(-γ_E-\frac{5}{6}+ln⁡(\frac{1}{cx}))$$

The above formula is valid for small values of $x$ only (shorter than reduced Compton wavelength),$ γ_E $ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant.

I forgot how to rescale (and, honestly, I was bad at natural units and stuff like that!! because i have bad memory). So, could some one kind please help me out, thank you guys.

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/494336/2451

Comment: That was a question i deleted long time ago because it was not edited well @Qmechanic

Comment: The recommended procedure for improving a question on SE is to edit the question within the same thread rather than starting new threads.

Comment: thank you very much for your recommendations @Qmechanic.

Comment: Your $\delta(x)$ is missing the prefactor $e^2/(4\pi\epsilon_0x)$.

Comment: To restore regular units, replace $1/(cx)$ in the logarithmic term with $λ ̅_C/x$.

Comment: Being able to go back from natural or atomic units to regular units is a critical skill for a physicist. You should practice to get comfortable doing it.

Comment: Thank you very much @G.Smith for your correction to my formula and giving me your answer. Many people gave me the same suggestions (i should learn how to deal with natural or atomic units), but i'm bad at tracking equations (as you saw, i just forgot the prefactor $e^2/(4πϵ_0x)$ over there), so, i will keep trying!!. But thank you for your answer.

Comment: I just added the missing prefactor $e^2/(4πϵ_0x)$ you mentioned @G.Smith.

Comment: Now the sign is wrong.

Comment: corrected @G.Smith